# Double Integral $\iint\limits_Se^{x+y}\,dx\,dy$ where $S=\{(x,y):|x|+|y|\le1\}$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, multiple-integral

Let $S=\{(x,y):|x|+|y|\le1\}$. How to evaluate
$$\iint_Se^{x+y}\,dx\,dy?$$
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Divide the domain in four pieces according to the signs of $x$, $y$.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla : Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: If you know the signs of $x$, $y$ the condition $|x|+|y|\le 1$ will be: $x+y\le 1$ when $x\ge 0$, $y\ge 0$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It helps if you can visualize the set $S$.  Notice that for any $x$ such that $\lvert x \rvert \leq 1$, we have 
$\lvert y \rvert \leq 1 - \lvert x \rvert$, or
$$
-1 + \lvert x \rvert \leq y \leq 1 - \lvert x \rvert.
$$
This can be broken down further, depending on the sign of $x$:
$$
\begin{cases}
-1+x \leq y \leq 1-x, & x \geq 0, \\
-1-x \leq y \leq 1+x, & x < 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Let's call these two triangular regions $S_+$ and $S_-$, respectively.
Here's a picture of the region $S = S_+ \cup S_-$.

[image: Closed disk in L^1 norm]

Integration will be with respect to $y$ first for a given fixed $x$ (satisfying $-1 \leq x \leq 1$), then with respect to $x$.  Due to the symmetry of the region and the integrand, these can be interchanged.
$$
\begin{align}
\iint_S e^{x+y} \, dx \, dy 
&= \iint_{S_-} e^{x+y} \, dx \, dy + \iint_{S+} e^{x+y} \, dx \, dy \\
&= \int_{-1}^{0} \int_{-1-x}^{1+x} e^{x+y} \, dy \, dx 
+ \int_{0}^{1} \int_{-1+x}^{1-x} e^{x+y} \, dy \, dx.
\end{align}
$$

Can you take it from there?